# Spring cloud bearer header pass through

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

This seems like a pretty common question, and has a simple answer however implementing the documented solution isn't working for me.

I have a zuul proxy/gateway for all incoming requests which then forwards those onto different micro services. Each incoming request has a correct bearer token set in the header (this is set and validated in the front end  (from okta) and confirmed it works when skipping Zuul and going direct to a service), I just need to pass that onto the micro services.

**EdgeServiceApplication**

```
@EnableHystrix
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@SpringBootApplication
public class EdgeServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EdgeServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Zuul application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8080

logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    org.springframework.security: INFO

zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
```

And on my micro services,

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class InstanceServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InstanceServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I try and send a request to a micro service through Zuul I get a 401 response.

When adding the following bean to my micro services I can see that there is no Authorisation header set when requests come from Zuul, however I can see it set when calling directly.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean requestDumperFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    Filter requestDumperFilter = new RequestDumperFilter();
    registration.setFilter(requestDumperFilter);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registration;
}
```

I'm new to Spring so just hoping I've missed something obviouse in a .yml file somewhere?

Current dependencies

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath('io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.4.RELEASE')
}
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-ribbon')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')

    compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.2.0.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security:1.2.1.RELEASE')
}
```

**Update:**

After changing my application as suggested I'm still hitting a 401 on any request.

```
2017-11-02 11:03:05.697 ERROR 7139 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 null] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:78) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
```

I'm starting to think there is something wrong somewhere else. I have a SecurityConfig class which looks like (not safe for production I know)

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

The only security configuration on my micro services are

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class InstanceServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InstanceServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    protected static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
            return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    protected ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter resourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated();
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean requestDumperFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        Filter requestDumperFilter = new RequestDumperFilter();
        registration.setFilter(requestDumperFilter);
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registration;
    }
}
```

**Update #2:**

Logging out the request headers, there is still no Authorization

```
2017-11-02 11:25:24.133  INFO 7381 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.e.s.c.LoggingRequestInterceptor      : URI         : http://instance-service
2017-11-02 11:25:24.133  INFO 7381 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.e.s.c.LoggingRequestInterceptor      : Method      : GET
2017-11-02 11:25:24.133  INFO 7381 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.e.s.c.LoggingRequestInterceptor      : Headers     : {Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*], Content-Length=[0]}
2017-11-02 11:25:24.133  INFO 7381 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.e.s.c.LoggingRequestInterceptor      : Request body:
```

**Update #3:**

I've made a quick sample application which also strips the authentication headers... https://github.com/peavers/zuul-oauth-passthrough - Hopefully someone can spot what I've done wrong.

Comment: what version of spring cloud do you use?

Comment: @DanyloZatorsky sorry I should have mentioned; have added my dependencies to the question.

Comment: As far as I know, spring-cloud dependencies separated from spring-boot dependencies. I am not sure about the versions of cloud starters in your case. Could you show the output of the `gradle dependencies` command?

Comment: Sure, it's rather long so have provided it via paste bin https://pastebin.com/rmLNNKyT

Comment: Ok, seems I got it and we are digging in a wrong direction. Will post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-netflix.adoc#cookies-and-sensitive-headers):

> The sensitiveHeaders are a blacklist and the default is not empty, so
>   to make Zuul send all headers (except the "ignored" ones) you would
>   have to explicitly set it to the empty list. This is necessary if you
>   want to pass cookie or authorization headers to your back end.

So the `sensitiveHeaders` work the other way around. They prevent headers from being downstreamed to your back-end. Instead of adding Authorization header to the list you should remove it from there like this:

```
zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

or like this (if you need Cookies to be downstreamed to your back-end for some reasons (I hope you don't) ):

```
zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders:
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately when setting `zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie` in my `application.yml` file I'm still hitting the same 401 response